# Spring Boot: How to return a BAD_REQUEST with an entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

In my `@RestController` I'd like to return a `BAD_REQUEST` if the entity already exists.

I did this:

```
if (entity != null)
  return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(entity);
```

The problem is that when I put it to test, I see an empty body.

Why?

Comment: Please provide more code. Shows us the test class. Show how the controller looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response Entity provides two nested builder interfaces. Hence we can access the capabilities directly through the static methods of ResponseEntity
Try this one:

```
if (entity != null)
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(entity);
```

Comment: apparently the entity was null.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
if (entity != null)
   return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(entity!=null){
    return new ResponseEntity<T>(entity, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

T is data type